# ubuntu 18.04 Untrusted application launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

I have some starters in a folder and When I double click on them, I get the message "Untrusted application launcher". If I click on "Trust and Launch" the program execute but is NEVER TRUSTED !!

I noticed that in the permissions of the starter, the security context is marked as "Unknown". Is that new in 18.04? How can I change it?

RD

[Example of error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWjzn.png)

Comment: welcome to askUbuntu! are you trying to run the application as root? try running it from the command line with sudo... what did you install? how are you launching it?

Comment: @Josuha Besneatle > I ask Steam or PlayOnLinux to deposit an icon (startup) on the desktop. I end up with a file "pgm.desktop" with the "text icon", no icon or the name from inside the startup. To start it, I double click an got the message above. The name inside the starter is "Age of Wonders III (Steam)"

Comment: By the way, my O/S is Ubuntu18.04 with Unity 7

Comment: I removed unity and when back to gnome! after I start the *.desktop file once (accepting the trust ...) the game Icon appears and I can execute the program without problems after that.